# MySQLi, Unable to load dynamic library php_mysqli.dll

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, http-status-code-500

Error:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I have this code,

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","rss","(pass removed)","rss");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members(username, password) VALUES('test', 'test'");

mysqli_close($con);
```

And it isn't working. PHP is saying MySQLi is not installed, but on `phpinfo()` it's fine?

I've installed `mysqli` with `apt-get install php7.0-mysql php7.0-mysqli`, still isn't working.

It is connecting to the database.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you have an extra closing brace at the end `}`

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on for your PHP code ? Or check the error logs maybe ?

Comment: Sorry - I removed some code from the script, I'll edit that out. It isn't that.

Comment: You're getting a 500 still and your error log isn't populated?

Comment: @chris85 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: That should be in the question. That is a configuration, not a script issue though. Are you running `phpinfo` on the same PHP version the script is running against?